# Displaying table header even when there is no content? (django admin page)

Tags: django, admin

I want the table to appear with all headings even when there is no content. Now, only 'Add' button appears when there isn't anything in the database. How do I do this? Please help

**It looks like this with no content:**

[image]

**It looks like this with content:**

[image]

So with no content, it should still show the table headings. Suggest any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the template at `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list_results.html` to your admin template folder.
Keep that structure:

`project
-app
-templates
    -admin
        -change_list_results.html
-manage.py`

Than, remove the `{% if results %} - {% endif %}` tags from the new template file and it should work.